# Do you have a life?

Tags: discussion, users

Some people on this site deserve an exceptional amount of respect, since they contribute to this site in such a way that it is almost unbelievable. I shall not mention any names, but I think you all know whom I refer to---and anyway, a quick glance at [the "Users" section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users) reveals their identities. With all the work they do, you would have thought answering questions on this site was their full-time occupation.

And this makes me wonder: **How much time do you spend on this site per day? How do you get time to live a life outside of the TeX world?**

(I am asking mostly because I am deeply impressed.)

Comment: Why a downvote now? The title was mostly meant to catch attention.

Comment: What downvote? I don't see any currently. Anyway, I considered downvoting (but didn't) because this question and its answers don't really have any relevance to the operation of the site other than the tangential fact that the users of the site have to spend some time to, well, use the site. The amount of time to spend is a personal decision each user makes for him/herself, and I don't really see the benefit of sharing that information with everyone else. The operation of the site will not really be affected by any answers to this question.

Comment: I browse on my lunch hour.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote but I did vote to close (could have picked any reason, off topic, too broad, opinion based)

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3942/when-are-you-not-on-tex-sx?rq=1 among others.

Comment: @Sean: I lunch on my browsing hour. `:)`

Comment: People, it has been an honour to be joking with you. Because the question is probably getting closed within less than two hours when the final vote arrives. `;-)`

Comment: I browse on my study hour; that is, when I'm supposed to be studying. ;-)